# Accessing a local program from Citrix VDI

Tags: windows, citrix

In a company I'm working for right now we're required to work via Virtual Desktop (Citrix) for security purposes. Everything is preset and at the moment they have blacklisted all internet domains so we can't do anything. However we have access to our local C:\ drive. What I'm trying to do at the moment is launch a program I have installed in my local machine through the Citrix virtual desktop. Although I can find the .exe in the file explorer when I try to launch the program it gives me a Network error:

> Windows cannot access \Client\C$\Program Files(x86)\My\Folder\bin\app.exe

How can I fix this? Can I change my local permissions or something to allow access? Is there any Citrix configuration that I can change?

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable and configure "Local App Access". However this is only valid for desktop sessions not application sessions.

> Local App Access seamlessly integrates locally installed Windows applications into a hosted desktop environment without changing from one computer to another. With Local App Access, you can:
>
> - Access applications installed locally on a physical laptop, PC, or other device directly from the virtual desktop.
> - Provide a flexible application delivery solution. If users have local applications that you cannot virtualize or that IT does not maintain, those applications still behave as though they are installed on a virtual desktop.
> - ...

Please refer to the [description](http://docs.citrix.com/en-us/xenapp-and-xendesktop/7-6/xad-build-new-enviroment/xad-laa-intro.html) and the [configuration](http://docs.citrix.com/en-us/xenapp-and-xendesktop/7-6/xad-build-new-enviroment/xad-laa-intro/xad-laa-config.html).

I linked to the version xendesktop 7.6 because I had to guess what version you are using.